# Clustering with mule esb community edition

Tags: mule, cluster-computing, mule-cluster

I use mule CE 3.3.0. I created cxf proxy service in my mule server.
My transaction number is pretty much so I want use the Clustering.
Can i install many mule esb instances over severals machines (physical or logical) and connect them together?

Comment: Why do you need clustering? What state do you need to share across the Mule instances?

Comment: @DavidDossot, I want it for my company. My company is a big central company and it is an intermediary between other companies. In fact, our company is the bridge between other companies. We have too many high transactions number. For this reason it's essential that my Mule has this feature.
And by the way, I really need to automatic load balancing of processing.

Comment: I'm trying to determine if you need clustering or if load balancing would be enough. The latter is easy to roll out, the former more complex, especially with CE. I still need to understand what state you need to share across Mule instances.

Comment: Also what inbound protocol(s) do you use for your flows? Some are easier to load balance than other. And what is your data storage technology of choice for shared state (DB, NoSQL...)? Do you use collection aggregators, idempotent filters, until successful message processors?

Comment: @DavidDossot, I use HTTP protocol for my flows. I don't use DataBase in my project no but I will need to use DB in next step. I Don't use collection aggregators, but I use Expression filter. result of serach just show clustering on the Enterprise edition, and unfortunately there are alittle content for CE edition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what you're saying in the comments (thank you for providing extra context BTW), it seems you do not need clustering then. You could run the same Mule configuration in different Mule instances and have an HTTP load balancer in front of them.

One thing I forgot to ask is: do you have polling endpoints? If yes, you'll have to start the polling flows only on one Mule instance to prevent multiple pollings of the same data.

Comment: Thanks @David for your reply. I don't have polling endpoints. so it doen't need that I worry about how clustering my mule project. I just have a HTTP load balancer in front, it's enough.

Comment: whats it the best way to insure the same Mule configuration across non clustered instances?

Comment: Do a Maven release so you end-up with a uniquely versionned application .zip you can then deploy to your servers. You can also use `jcabi-manifests` to retrieve infos from the application's meta-inf (like Maven version, Git revision number via the buildnumber-maven-plugin) and expose them behind a custom resource or an HTTP response header. That way you have confirmation of what is exactly running where.